# How do you connect 1 or more Waveshare 2.9inch eInk to Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (2018)?

Tags: pi-4, spi, pi-models, eink

Apologies for this newbie question, but I am not sure how to safely (?) connect at least one Waveshare 2.9inch eInk module to a Rasp Pi 4 Model B.

I am assuming that the colored wires go into some of the ports in the GPIO module (?). I have looked at the specifications for both and have not been able to find a tutorial for this particular model. Please help!

Photo shown below:

[image]

Comment: what do you see in the middle of the module?

Comment: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/2.9inch_e-Paper_Module_Manual#Users_Guides_of_Raspberry_Pi ?

Comment: how would that work for 2 spi displays @Dirk

Comment: @jsotola what should i see in the middle (?)

Comment: You asked for 1 or more. Above shows the solution for 1.... You may be able to use a different SPI channel, but you would also need to use different pins for RST, etc. *And* modify the code

Comment: I think @jsotola was indicating that you need to use the SPI interface as the text (and pin names) on the board hints at

Comment: what would happen if i get the pins mixed up? would it damage the board (?)